# How to Print 2D array

Tags: arrays, list, printing, floating-point, ocaml

What is wrong here?

```
let elem = function(list)-> (List.map string_of_int list);;
let rec row = function (list)->if elem(List.hd list)::row(List.tl list);;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to give some advices about your code :

1 - We do not put the arguments between parenthesis when it's not ambiguous :

```
let elem = fun l -> String.concat " " (List.map string_of_float l)
```

2 - Instead to use `if` `then` `else`, use pattern matching on a list. It's more efficient and your code will be more readable:

```
let rec row = function
  | [] ->  []
  | x :: tl -> elem x :: row tl
```

This function is not tail-recursive (change into it can be an exercise for you)

I also put your last function here :

```
let print = fun l -> print_string (String.concat "\n" (row l))

let () = 
 (print [[0.2;-0.2;0.2];[0.1;-0.1;0.1];[0.5;-0.5;0.5]])
```

Here my version :

`let string_of_float_list l = String.concat " " (List.map string_of_float l)`

`let float_list_to_string l = String.concat "\n" (List.map string_of_float_list l)`

`let () = 
  Printf.printf "%s" (float_list_to_string [[1.0;2.0;3.0];[1.0;2.0;3.0];[1.0;2.0;3.0]])`

Output :

```
1. 2. 3.
1. 2. 3.
1. 2. 3.
```

Comment: Also in `function l -> match l with | patterns -> ...` you can just type in `function | patterns ...`